# R - how to conditionally replace character strings with missing

Tags: r

I am attempting to replace all character values that are not equal to "A" or "B", to ""

```
df$var <- as.character(df$var)
df$var[df$var != "A" | "B"] <- c("")
```

I'm sure there  is a simple solution to this... however my novice is showing and I can't find the help topic (on here or otherwise).

Any help?

Comment: I won't post it as answer because it's too similar to the other answer, but you were almost there. It is always better to operate on part of the data than on all of it, so you could do either: `df$var[!df$var %in% c("A", "B")] <- ""` or (like in @nrussells comment) `df$var[df$var != "A" & df$var != "B"] <- ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df$var <- ifelse(!(df$var %in% c("A","B")), "", df$var)
```

Comment: Because `df$var[df$var != "A" | "B"]` is not a valid R command. It would have to be `df$var[df$var != "A" & df$var != "B"]`. Or one of the many other ways to accomplish this in R; but `df$var != "A" | "B"` is not legal.

Comment: Ofcourse it's not, but it's better to operate on part of the vector than on all of it. Your example is much better than the answer

Comment: Thank you guys - still understanding the nuances of what is "legal" and not in R. Good examples from both of you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use `gsub`:

```
x <- unlist(strsplit('ABCDEABCDE', '')) # example vector
gsub('[^AB]', '', x)
#  [1] "A" "B" ""  ""  ""  "A" "B" ""  ""  ""
```